# share a struct in c++ and c?

Tags: c++, struct

say a define a struct in header file of c++, foo.h

```
typedef struct {
    ...
}foo;
```

in .c file I include the foo.h, then

```
foo* fooPtr;
```

will it work?

Comment: Maybe.  What's in the struct?

Comment: What happened when you tried this? Did you get any errors?

Comment: Probably, did it work for you?

Comment: No. I don't think that C likes those three little dots between the 2 squigglies.

Comment: This FQA page might be helpful for you: http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/mixing.html

Comment: You can just use `struct foo { ... };` because typedef enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on what is actually in the struct `foo`.  If the struct is simply data and has no behavior itself or in any of it's member fields then it **should** work just fine in C or C++.  If it has any type of explicit or implicit behavior (think generated destructors) then no it won't work properly in C.

For example:

```
// Works fine in C or C++ irrespective of where it was defined 
typedef struct { 
  int field1;
} foo;

// Will have different behavior if it compiles at all.
struct bar { 
  ~bar() {
    // destructor code
  }
};

typedef struct { 
  bar b; 
} foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

The C++ `struct` declaration is compliant with the C language as long as it does not have any C++ features; a plain, C language, declaration.  For example, no `private` declarations.